# Is there a way to set the default SMB version to SMB1 globally on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, server-message-block, veeam

I am trying to configure multiple servers running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS to backup using the Veeam Linux Agent (VLA) to a Qnap NAS hosted remotely by our IT. For whatever reason, we are required to do so by using the SMB connection option in VLA. Additionally, we are not permitted to just mount the drive in `/etc/fstab` as a workaround. Whenever I try to connect via this method, I receive the following error:

```
         mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
                        Exit code: [32]                  
            Failed to execute script command mount       
 Unable mount device[//server/directory] to [/tmp/veeam/servernamedirectoryname].
```

The following entries are found in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
kernel: [75155.992699] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
kernel: [75156.012537] CIFS VFS: Dialect not supported by server. Consider specifying vers=1.0 or vers=2.0 on mount for accessing older servers
kernel: [75156.012561] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

It's apparent that I'm trying to connect via SMB2 or SMB3 but need to connect using SMB1. I confirmed then by mounting the drive via `mount -v -t cifs //qnap/backups /mnt/backups -o username=user,password=*******,domain=domain,vers=1.0`

I've confirmed with Veeam that they do not provide an option with their software to specify and SMB version. I've googled and many sites have said that SMB version can be forced by adding the following lines in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
min protocol = SMB1
max protocol = SMB1
```

...but that doesn't seem to have any affect whatsoever, and I thought that was only for serving via Samba, not for using SMB as a client. So, is there a way to set SMB to use SMB1 globally?

It should be noted that some servers being used in the company work with Veeam. They are running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I've tried updating the servers which upgrade to 16.04.4 LTS, but they still don't work. We are unable to locate the differences between the two.

Comment: Wouldn't be best to remove the support for smb1 from your qnap server?

Comment: You set it in the mount options as you already did. There is nothing else. Of course, you need to be eliminating SMB1 from your organization, not expanding it.

Comment: @FedericoGalli Yes it would, however that is not a decision I am able to make and I'm trying to work within the confines of what we currently have.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I agree on the need to eliminate SMB1, however I am just trying to work with what we currently have. Also, as I stated in the OP, I am unfortunately not able to mount the share and use it that way. Instead, I have to use the functionality provided by the Veeam client.

Comment: I had recently a similar issue in our organization but I was able to "update" the nas config. As far as I know you can set vers=1.0 on command line or on fstab, as you can confirm with your test. Perhaps it could be possible to modify the veam call?

Comment: @FedericoGalli so I discussed the issue with IT and we were able to update SMB to 3.0 on the Qnap NAS and everything works now.

Comment: well done! it was the right choice